# Approximate solution to system of polynomial equations

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials, approximation

I'd like to solve approximately the following system of equations for $a_1$, $a_2$, $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ all real and nonzero:

$a_1(1+4\alpha_2)^3+8a_2(1+4\alpha_1)^2+\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{64}(1+4\alpha_1)^2(1+4\alpha_2)^3=0$

$a_1(1+4\alpha_2)^5+16a_2(1+4\alpha_1)^4-\frac{11\sqrt{\pi}}{512}(1+4\alpha_1)^4(1+4\alpha_2)^5=0$

$a_1(1+4\alpha_2)^7+24a_2(1+4\alpha_1)^6-\frac{65\sqrt{\pi}}{8192}(1+4\alpha_1)^6(1+4\alpha_2)^7=0$

$a_1(1+4\alpha_2)^9+32a_2(1+4\alpha_1)^8-\frac{291\sqrt{\pi}}{65536}(1+4\alpha_1)^8(1+4\alpha_2)^9=0$

where I know that some approximate solutions are

$a_1 = 117.429,\ \  a_2 = -755.468,\ \  \alpha_1 = 1.3177,\ \  \alpha_2 = 2.9026$

I'd like to improve on these or at least confirm them. Plotting the equations in one parameter while keeping the other three as above I see that there are indeed roots there, e.g:

```
a2 = -755.468; alpha1 = 1.3177; alpha2 = 2.9026;
```

and:

```
Plot[a1/(1 + 4 alpha1)^2 + (8 a2)/(1 + 4 alpha2)^3 +  Sqrt[Pi]/64, {a1, 110, 120}, 
  PlotRange -> {{110, 120}, {-0.1, 0.1}}]
```

I've tried using `FindRoot` with different parameters (accuracies, iterations, methods), but I end up with `Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within # iterations`, and results which are completely different. One example:

```
FindRoot[{a1 (1 + 4alpha2)^3 + 8 a2 (1 + 4alpha1)^2 + 
  Sqrt[Pi] (1 +4 alpha1)^2 (1 +4 alpha2)^3/64 , 
  a1 (1 +4 alpha2)^5 + 16 a2 (1 +4 alpha1)^4 - 
  11 Sqrt[Pi] (1 + 4alpha1)^4 (1 + 4alpha2)^5/512 , 
  a1 (1 +4 alpha2)^7 + 24 a2 (1 + 4alpha1)^6 - 
  65 Sqrt[Pi] (1 +4 alpha1)^6 (1 + 4alpha2)^7/8192 , 
  a1 (1 +4 alpha2)^9 + 32 a2 (1 + 4alpha1)^8 - 
  291 Sqrt[Pi] (1 + 4alpha1)^8 (1 + 4alpha2)^9/65536}, {{a1, 110, 
  120}, {a2, -760, -750}, {alpha1, 1.3, 1.4}, {alpha2, 2.9, 3}}, 
  MaxIterations -> 100000, WorkingPrecision -> 50]
```

Gives the error above and

$a_1 \rightarrow 0.631165832,$

$a_2 \rightarrow -70.5406787,$

$\alpha_1 \rightarrow 0.30522891, $

$\alpha_2 \rightarrow 3.7582495135$.

Any ideas how I can improve on this?

Answer (score 4):

You can actually solve the whole system:

```
sol = Solve[{a1 (1 + alpha2)^3 + 8 a2 (1 + alpha1)^2 + 
  Sqrt[Pi] (1 + alpha1)^2 (1 + alpha2)^3/64 == 0, 
a1 (1 + alpha2)^5 + 16 a2 (1 + alpha1)^4 - 
  11 Sqrt[Pi] (1 + alpha1)^4 (1 + alpha2)^5/512 == 0, 
a1 (1 + alpha2)^7 + 24 a2 (1 + alpha1)^6 - 
  65 Sqrt[Pi] (1 + alpha1)^6 (1 + alpha2)^7/8192 == 0, 
a1 (1 + alpha2)^9 + 32 a2 (1 + alpha1)^8 - 
  291 Sqrt[Pi] (1 + alpha1)^8 (1 + alpha2)^9/65536 == 0}, {a1, a2,
 alpha1, alpha2}];
```

This returns a very large equation with 39 different solutions. You can look at the individual solutions:

```
sol[[20]]//N
```

or scan through them:

```
Manipulate[sol[[i]] // N, {i, 1, Length[sol], 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It highlighted what I forgot to mention in the OP: the coefficients must be real and nonzero. With that constraint `Solve` doesn't give any answers. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

For confirmation of your approximate root you can simply replace it into the expression and see if everything is close to 0:

```
expr = {a1 (1 + 4 alpha2)^3 + 8 a2 (1 + 4 alpha1)^2 + 
   Sqrt[Pi] (1 + 4 alpha1)^2 (1 + 4 alpha2)^3/64, 
   a1 (1 + 4 alpha2)^5 + 16 a2 (1 + 4 alpha1)^4 - 
    11 Sqrt[Pi] (1 + 4 alpha1)^4 (1 + 4 alpha2)^5/512, 
   a1 (1 + 4 alpha2)^7 + 24 a2 (1 + 4 alpha1)^6 - 
    65 Sqrt[Pi] (1 + 4 alpha1)^6 (1 + 4 alpha2)^7/8192, 
   a1 (1 + 4 alpha2)^9 + 32 a2 (1 + 4 alpha1)^8 - 
    291 Sqrt[Pi] (1 + 4 alpha1)^8 (1 + 4 alpha2)^9/65536};

knownApprox = {a1 -> 117.429, a2 -> -755.468, alpha1 -> 1.3177, alpha2 -> 2.9026};
expr/.knownApprox//Abs//Max
(* 1.50862*10^14    oops *)
```

At least [`NMinimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NMinimize.html) can find a solution by minimizing the sum of the absolute values:

```
NMinimize[Total@Abs@expr, {a1, a2, alpha1, alpha2}]
(* {3.45995*10^-6, 
    {a1 -> -0.50239, a2 -> 1.15054, alpha1 -> -0.251652, alpha2 -> -0.226791}} *)

(* You can put in constraints if you want a solution within some region *)
NMinimize[{Total@Abs@expr, a1 > 110 && a2 < -700}, {a1, a2, alpha1, alpha2}]
```

There is lots of good documentation on `NMinimize` in the [Optimization tutorails](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html#217856200)

Comment: Thanks! This shows a mistake I made: the system of equations in the OP have been manipulated as if the $=0$'s are exact; namely I multiplied the first equation with $(1+4\alpha_1)^2(1+4\alpha_2)^3$ and correspondingly for the rest (the original equations are like the one in my `Plot` in the OP). Using the original equations with the stated coefficients the sum of the absolute values is $0.0204887$, slightly better than $0.060103232$, which `NMinimize` gives us with `WorkingPrecision` $50$ and $10^6$ iterations. Still not sure how the stated coefficients came about.

Comment: Actually, using `FindRoot` with the original equations gives answers pretty close to the stated coefficients, presumably I can get closer with higher number of iterations.